# Time variable in Lorentz transformations

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

When an object goes with a speed near from the light celerity, it inflates in the direction of its speed. The inflation rate is given by Lorentz transformations as follows:

$x'= γ(x-vt)$

where $v$ is the speed of the object and $γ$ the well-known coefficient of relativity.
My question is: what time does $t$ refer to? Is it a variation of time, in which case one should call it $Δt$, or is it a fixed time?

Comment: t and x are coordinates of an event. If x=x(t) and t is running, then you get the trajectory of a point particle which passes the position x at the time t.

Comment: If the origins  $\:O\:$ and  $\:O'\:$ of the common $\:Ox,O'x'\:$ axis coincide at a moment , then this event could defined as $\:(x=0,t=0)\:$ in the unprimed system and  as $\:(x'=0,t'=0)\:$ in the primed system.
Then all these variables are coordinates and
\begin{align}
x' & = \gamma \left( x-v\;t \right)
\tag{01a}\\
t' & = \gamma \left( t-\dfrac{v\;x}{c^2}\right)
\tag{01b}
\end{align}

Comment: But **in any case** you can use differences or differentials
 
\begin{align}
\Delta x' & = \gamma \left( \Delta x-v\;\Delta t \right)
\tag{02a}\\
\Delta t' & = \gamma \left(\Delta t-\dfrac{v\;\Delta x}{c^2}\right)
\tag{02b}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathrm{d} x' & = \gamma \left(\mathrm{d} x-v\;\mathrm{d} t \right)
\tag{03a}\\
\mathrm{d} t' & = \gamma \left(\mathrm{d}  t-\dfrac{v\;\mathrm{d} x}{c^2}\right)
\tag{03b}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It's the time coordinate of an event in the $S$ frame (the coordinate frame you're moving with respect to), then a fixed time.

Important remark: the equation that you are using does not give the **decrease** (not inflation) in length of an object as measured by an observer who's moving with respect to the $S$ frame, but the $x$ coordinate transformation between those two frames. For comparing this decrease in length, you should use the [length contraction equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction): $$L'=\frac{L_0}{\gamma}$$ For comparing the difference of elapsed time between two events in two different coordinate frames, use instead the [time dilation equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Simple_inference_of_time_dilation_due_to_relative_velocity).

Comment: To be sure, the time dilation equation assumes the two events are co-located in the unprimed coordinate frame, i.e., $\Delta x = 0$